# Join common columns from different tables and select first most filled

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables: A, B, and C.
Records in B and C contain columns data1 and data2 which nullable, and id_A.

I need to receive any for both data1 and data2 per record in A (all columns from A).

Table A (other columns omitted):

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table B:

```
id | id_A | data1 | data2
1    1      b11     null
2    1      null    b12
3    2      null    b22
4    5      b51     null
```

Table C:

```
id | id_A | data1 | data2
1    1      c11     c12
2    2      c21     null
3    3      c31     null
4    5      c51     null
```

Result:

```
id | data1 | data2
1    b11     b12
2    c21     b22
3    c31     null
4    null    null
5    b51     null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `left join` and aggregation:

```
select a.id, coalesce(max(b.data1), max(c.data1)) as data1,
       coalesce(max(b.data2), max(c.data2)) as data2
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id_a left join
     c
     on a.id = c.id_a
group by a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use - COALESCE (val1, val2, val3...)

```
select a.id, coalesce(b.data1,c.data1), coalesce(b.data2,c.data2) from Aleft join B on .id=b.id_a left join C on a.id=c.id_a
```